Optimal Trade Entries in KDB
Given ohlcv data such as
q) ohlcv
ticker   time                     open    high    low     close   volume
------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBM 2024.04.08D09:15:00.000000000 2925.2  2930.15 2922    2929    38088 
IBM 2024.04.08D09:16:00.000000000 2931    2935    2929.4  2933.3  33140 
IBM 2024.04.08D09:17:00.000000000 2932.3  2934    2931.8  2933.9  18341 
IBM 2024.04.08D09:18:00.000000000 2934.25 2934.3  2930.5  2930.5  16803 
IBM 2024.04.08D09:19:00.000000000 2930.5  2932    2929.2  2931.45 33574 

what'd be an efficient way of finding all the rows where if a trade was initiated, over the next n bars (including the given entry bar), the profit at any time in the window exceeds a threshold p, but before a negative loss limit l is hit?

Will likely need more details here to answer. At what price would an entry be initiated? Would it be long or short? What size would the entry be? What price would the unrealised pnl be marked to? What if the exit size exceeds the volume in the period, split the exit over two bars?

Sure, Terry. Each of the first bars of the n sized sliding windows would be a candidate. For now the positions can be exclusively LONG for the short side should be straightforward. The entry size does not matter, and might as well be one. Note sure I'm answering your last question satisfactorily, but the unrealised pnl would be marked to the closing price of its bar. However, one would need to check e.g., that the bar high/lows are not breached given the criterion I set.

Here's my solution, although I'm pretty sure there's something far more elegant out there.
swin:{[n;L] s:til (1+L-n); flip (s;(n-1)+s)} / SLIDING WINDOWS n: window size, L: length of list
r:{[n;x] (-1+(x%n))}; / returns
exitCond:{[tp;sl;rl;rh;side]
    if[side=`LONG; r:(rh>=tp) or (rl<=-1*sl)];
    if[side=`SHORT; r:(rh>=sl) or (rl<=(-1*tp))];
    r
 };
singleEntry:{[w;tp;sl;side]
    w:update entryPrice:first close, entryTime:first time, exitPrice:close, exitTime:time, mode:side by ticker from w;
    w:update rl:r[entryPrice; low], rh:r[entryPrice; high], rc:r[entryPrice; close] by ticker from w;
    w:update rh:0f, rl:0f by ticker from w where time=first time; / not interested in the first bar's highs and lows for comparison purposes
    w:select from w where exitCond[tp; sl; rl; rh; side],i=(first;i) fby ticker
 };

tp:0.005; / take profit as a POSITIVE proportion of the entryPrice
sl:0.005; / stop loss as a POSITIVE proportion of the entryPrice
n:10; / rolling/sliding window size
side:`LONG; / side of the trade
w:swin[n; count ohlcv];
show entries:raze {[ohlcv;tp;sl;side;x]
                 t:select from ohlcv where ((i>=x[0]) and (i<=x[1]));
                 r:singleEntry[t; tp; sl; side];
                 r:delete time, open, high, low, close, volume from r;
                 if[side=`LONG; r:select from r where rh>=tp;];
                 if[side=`SHORT; r:select from r where rl<=-1*tp;];
                 r
              }[ohlcv; tp; sl; side] peach w;

